# Pandas Groupby on a specific value of a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this sample data here that I'm trying to aggregate:

```
Ticket ID   User    Date        Category
1926        a       1/1/2020    cat_7
1947        a       1/1/2020    cat_6
1901        c       1/2/2020    cat_7
1067        a       1/3/2020    cat_1
1683        a       1/4/2020    cat_3
1281        a       1/4/2020    cat_3
1561        a       1/5/2020    cat_5
1932        a       1/5/2020    cat_5
1234        c       1/5/2020    cat_6
1013        c       1/7/2020    cat_7
1575        b       1/9/2020    cat_8
1152        b       1/10/2020   cat_4
1235        c       1/10/2020   cat_7
1596        b       1/11/2020   cat_4
1523        c       1/11/2020   cat_1
1447        b       1/12/2020   cat_4
1576        b       1/12/2020   cat_5
1260        c       1/13/2020   cat_2
1556        b       1/15/2020   cat_5
1838        b       1/16/2020   cat_5
1182        b       1/17/2020   cat_5
```

**Into this expected output:**

```
User    Category 1  Next Category   Count
a       cat_1       cat_3           2
                    cat_5           2
b       cat_1       cat_4           3
                    cat_5           4
c       cat_1       cat_2           1
```

I'm not sure if a specific value from a column can be extracted and used to groupby the actvities happened after **cat_1**

My failed attempt:

```
df.groupby(["User", "Category"])["Ticket ID"].count()
```

Which resulted to this:

```
User  Category    Count
a     cat_1       1
      cat_3       2
      cat_5       2
      cat_6       1
      cat_7       1
b     cat_1       1
      cat_4       3
      cat_5       4
c     cat_1       1
      cat_2       1
      cat_6       1
      cat_7       3
      cat_8       1
```

Comment: Why `cat_6` and `cat_7` doesn't appears for user `a` in the desired output ?

Comment: Hello, that's because `cat_6` and `cat 7` happened before `cat_1` in user `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def f(x):
    x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
    return x.iloc[x[x["Category"].eq('cat_1')].index[0]+1:]

df.groupby("User")\
    .apply(f) \
    .reset_index(drop=True) \
    .groupby(["User", "Category"]) \
    .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"}) \
    .assign(Category_1="cat_1") \
    .set_index("Category_1", append=True)\
    .reorder_levels([0, 2, 1])
```

**Explanations**:

There are two main steps:

- For each `User` group, remove rows before the first `cat_1` Category value
- Compute the `count` on each `["User", "Category"]`

The steps are:

1. Group the dataset according the `"User"` column using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
2. Filter all rows to only select rows after the first `cat_1` occurrence with the `f` function.

   1. Firstly reset index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).
   2. Select the index of the first `cat_1` row using `x[x["Category"].eq('cat_1')].index[0]`
   3. Add `+1` to the index from previous stap as we don't want the `cat_1` row.
   4. Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to slice rows before the index defined step 2.3.
3. Remove the redundant `User` index with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=True`
4. Group the dataframe according `User` and `Category` column using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
5. Aggregate the columns using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and count all the `Ticket_id`.

Here we have the output values. The next steps are here to match the desired *expected output*.

6. Rename the `count` output to `count` using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).
7. Add the `Category_1` column using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
8. Set the `Category_1` column as index using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True`
9. Reorder the index levels using [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html)

---

**Full code + illustration**

```py
def f(x):
    x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
    return x.iloc[x[x["Category"].eq('cat_1')].index[0]+1:]


# Step 2
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f))
#         Ticket ID User       Date Category
# User
# a    3       1683    a   1/4/2020    cat_3
#      4       1281    a   1/4/2020    cat_3
#      5       1561    a   1/5/2020    cat_5
#      6       1932    a   1/5/2020    cat_5
# b    1       1152    b  1/10/2020    cat_4
#      2       1596    b  1/11/2020    cat_4
#      3       1447    b  1/12/2020    cat_4
#      4       1576    b  1/12/2020    cat_5
#      5       1556    b  1/15/2020    cat_5
#      6       1838    b  1/16/2020    cat_5
#      7       1182    b  1/17/2020    cat_5
# c    6       1260    c  1/13/2020    cat_2

# Step 3
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
#     Ticket ID User       Date Category
# 0        1683    a   1/4/2020    cat_3
# 1        1281    a   1/4/2020    cat_3
# 2        1561    a   1/5/2020    cat_5
# 3        1932    a   1/5/2020    cat_5
# 4        1152    b  1/10/2020    cat_4
# 5        1596    b  1/11/2020    cat_4
# 6        1447    b  1/12/2020    cat_4
# 7        1576    b  1/12/2020    cat_5
# 8        1556    b  1/15/2020    cat_5
# 9        1838    b  1/16/2020    cat_5
# 10       1182    b  1/17/2020    cat_5
# 11       1260    c  1/13/2020    cat_2

# Step 5
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"}))
#                Ticket ID
# User Category
# a    cat_3             2
#      cat_5             2
# b    cat_4             3
#      cat_5             4
# c    cat_2             1

# Step 6
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .rename(columns={"Ticket ID": "count"}))
#                count
# User Category
# a    cat_3         2
#      cat_5         2
# b    cat_4         3
#      cat_5         4
# c    cat_2         1

print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .rename(columns={"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .assign(Category_1="cat_1")
        .set_index("Category_1", append=True)
        .reorder_levels([0, 2, 1]))
#                           count
# User Category_1 Category
# a    cat_1      cat_3         2
#                 cat_5         2
# b    cat_1      cat_4         3
#                 cat_5         4
# c    cat_1      cat_2         1
#                count Category_1

# Step 7
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .rename(columns={"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .assign(Category_1="cat_1"))
# User Category
# a    cat_3         2      cat_1
#      cat_5         2      cat_1
# b    cat_4         3      cat_1
#      cat_5         4      cat_1
# c    cat_2         1      cat_1
#                           count

# Step 8
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .rename(columns={"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .assign(Category_1="cat_1")
        .set_index("Category_1", append=True))
# User Category Category_1
# a    cat_3    cat_1           2
#      cat_5    cat_1           2
# b    cat_4    cat_1           3
#      cat_5    cat_1           4
# c    cat_2    cat_1           1
#                           count

# Step 9
print(df.groupby("User")
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .groupby(["User", "Category"])
        .agg({"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .rename(columns={"Ticket ID": "count"})
        .assign(Category_1="cat_1")
        .set_index("Category_1", append=True)
        .reorder_levels([0, 2, 1]))
# User Category_1 Category
# a    cat_1      cat_3         2
#                 cat_5         2
# b    cat_1      cat_4         3
#                 cat_5         4
# c    cat_1      cat_2         1
```

Comment: That was very detailed and I learn alot coming from how you elaborate the steps needed to aggregate the data

Comment: That is one detailed explanation. :-)